# Emphasizing words within a string using the listings package in LaTeX

Tags: listings

I'm using the listings-package for LaTeX to format source-codes within my document. I can emphasize keywords using the emph-option of the listings package:

```
\lstset{
    emph={nerv},
    emphstyle={\color{red}\textbf}
}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=trBL,
    caption={R-Code (test).},
    label={code:R_allee}
]
# comment
square <- function(x) {
    x^2
}

nerv = "Str ing "

x <- c(1:100)
y <- square(x)
\end{lstlisting}
```

This makes the "nerv" withing my source code bold and red. But, I want to highlight the "ing" withing the String "Str ing " using:

```
\lstset{
    emph={ing},
    emphstyle={\color{red}\textbf}
}
```

Unfortunately that does not work. I couldn't figure out what might solve the problem.

Does anyone of you have an idea?

Comment: This example works fine for me. Included only `listings` and `xcolor` in the document preamble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that this may be a moot point, since you only provide a minimal example. However, I also assume that highlighting the string `ing` in `"Str ing "` may be limited to only that specific instance in your code. For that, there is no need to define a style that is **global** to the entire listing. You could momentarily *escape* the listings environment (producing a **local** change), and typeset something using standard LaTeX by setting the `mathescape=true` flag:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
    emph={ing},
    emphstyle={\color{red}\textit}
}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=trBL,mathescape=true,
    caption={R-Code (test).},
    label={code:R_allee}
]
# comment
square <- function(x) {
    x^2
}

nerv = "Str $\color{blue}\textbf{ing}$ "
burn ing = hot

x <- c(1:100)
y <- square(x)
\end{lstlisting}

​\end{document}​
```

[image: mathescape from within lstlisting]

Another good example of such an illustration: [Lstlistings: Getting pretty equations in display mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22635/lstlistings-getting-pretty-equations-in-display-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem today and found another solution to this rather old question. The `listings` package allows us to define delimiters inside of which the package will still process keywords and other stuff. From the `listings` documentation:

> You can even let the package detect keywords, comments, strings, and other de-
>   limiters inside the contents.
>
> `\lstset{moredelim=*[s][\itshape]{/*}{*/}}`

The `*` modifier also works on string definitions so we can define our own strings that still allow keywords inside of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\lstset{
    emph={ing},
    emphstyle={\color{red}\textit},
    morestring=*[b]"  % the quote may be escaped by a _b_ackslash
}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=trBL,mathescape=true,
    caption={R-Code (test).},
    label={code:R_allee}
]
# comment
square <- function(x) {
    x^2
}

nerv = "Str ing"
burn ing = hot

x <- c(1:100)
y <- square(x)
\end{lstlisting}
​\end{document}
```

Note that the "ing" still has to be its own identifier, though.
[image]